# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jasmine

- I am new to js and jasmine
- I am trying to right a jasmine test case for my method.
- But I am facing an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.`
- I tried various ways of passing array into my method sports but still I am getting same error. Can you guys tell me how to fix it?

The test

```
it('Read player hiking', (done) => {
    let callFirstTime : boolean = true;
    let url=

    spyOn(swimming.playerhikings.movieService,'getResponse').and.
        callFake(() => { 
                if(callFirstTime){
                    callFirstTime = false; // Invoked by detectChanges() 
                    return Observable.of([{
                        "hikingId": "100",
                        "hikingName": "http://localhost:3000/assets/js/actualairings.json",
                        "hikingType": "TITLE",
                        "hikingData": "YWZjYXJlZ2Vyamh2dmFyZWdoYnZi",
                        "notes": "",
                        "notesId": "100",
                        "elfDocID": "100",
                        "url": "http://localhost:3000/upload",
                        "date": "06/27/2017",
                        "addedByName": "Kamal",
                        "userID": "206509786",
                        "operationType": "create"
                      }, {
                        "hikingId": "101",
                        "hikingName": "uploadTest4.txt",
                        "hikingType": "TITLE",
                        "hikingData": "Manish",
                        "notes": "",
                        "notesId": "101",
                        "elfDocID": "101",
                        "url": "http://localhost:3000/upload",
                        "date": "06/27/2017",
                        "addedByName": "Kamal",
                        "userID": "206509786",
                        "operationType": "create"
                      }]
                );
                }
         });

         //const args = ['p0', 'p1', 'p2'];
        //call_me.apply(this, args);

         var fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana'];
         var fruits1 = {"test": "1"};

          //console.log("swimming.playerhikings---->" + 
          //      JSON.stringify(swimming.playerhikings.sports.apply(this, args)));

         //spyOn(swimming.playerhikings.gridkendo,'enableSavehiking').and.returnValue(null);
         //swimming.playerhikings.fileSelect = "text.txt";
         //swimming.playerhikings.sports(fruits[0]);
        swimming.playerhikings.sports(fruits1.test);

         //swimming.playerhikings.coffee( {0: File, length: 1});
         //console.log("swimming.playerhikings._dataSource._data.length---->" + swimming.playerhikings._dataSource._data.length);
         fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
       done();
       //expect(swimming.playerhikings._dataSource._data.length).toEqual(3);
    });

});
```

The code

```
sports(inputValue: any): void {
  var that = this;
  var file: File = inputValue.files[0];

  var myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
  myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
    this.encodeBase64 = myReader.result;
    that.fileSelect = $("#attachhikingBrowseBtn").val().replace(/^.*\\/, "");
    if (that.fileSelect == '') {
      that.dragDrop = that.clearBtn;
    } else {
      that.dragDrop = "";
      that.dragDrop = that.fileSelect;
    }
  }
  $('.addELFhikingForm').show();
  if (inputValue.files.length > 0) {
    var fileSize = 0;

    fileSize = inputValue.files[0].size / 1048576; //size in mb 

    if (fileSize > 5) {
      alert("The hiking size exceeds the max limit of 5 MB");

      //confirm("The hiking size exceeds the max limit of 5 MB");

    }
    myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have exactly what error message tells you: getting property '0' of undefined:

```
var fruits1 = {"test": "1"};
swimming.playerhikings.sports(fruits1.test);
```

And:

```
sports(inputValue: any): void {
  var that = this;
  var file: File = inputValue.files[0];
                             ^^^^^^ undefined
}
```

Comment: @texirv what do you mean?

Comment: can you tell me how to pass in sports method         swimming.playerhikings.sports(fruits1.test);

Comment: sports({files: /*your file here*/}); in fact I don't know how and why you want to do that

Comment: can I give like this??  
sports({files: "test.tx"});

Comment: hey but I am getting an error like this now :( TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

Comment: can you tell me how to proceed :(